# Local Font in Next.js 13 not rendering using Tailwind

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

So I'm using localFont as in the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization) for a Next.js 13 app I'm building.

I've followed the steps but the font isn't rendering at all.

Here is the code in my _app.tsx file.

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import localFont from "@next/font/local";

const seasons = localFont({
  src: "../public/fonts/theseasons-reg-webfont.woff2",

  variable: "--font-seasons",
});

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <main className="{`${seasons.variable} font-sans`}">
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </main>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

and my tailwind.config.js

```
const { fontFamily } = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        nude: "#E5DDD6",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["var(--font-seasons)"],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

I've used the documentation and also looked on Youtube for solutions

Comment: When you look in your browser's dev tools, what is the value for `--font-seasons`?

Comment: Hey Ed, it reads like this in dev tools. But it's defaulting to Times.

<main class="{`${seasons.variable} font-sans`}">

Comment: You can find the values for all of your CSS variables in the Styles sidebar of your dev tools (when using the "Elements" (Chrome) or "Inspector" (Firefox) tab). Perhaps check there for the value of `--font-seasons`.

Comment: I also just noticed that you have unnecessary double quotes surrounding your `className` value (the one containing `font-sans`). Removing those should help at least get the right values into your `<main>`.

Comment: @EdLucas removing those double quotes fixed it! thank you!

Comment: @RishiPatel perhaps mark this in the answer and mark it answered.  I almost didn't spot this comment

Comment: Do you need both ' ${seasons.variable} font-sans' to make it work? I am trying to get just "font-sans" to work in my next14 app. Isn't that the right approach?